# Get object x/y coordinates + NSTimer crash for unknown reason

Tags: swift, coordinates, nstimer

1. Is there a command to get an object's x/y coordinates? Also, is there anyway to get the coordinates of the center of the screen?
2. I'm trying use an `NSTimer` to add a `CircleView` every second, but it's crashing unexpectedly.

   ```
   var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector(view.addSubview(circleView)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
   ```

   This is the `circleView` passed to `Selector(view.addSubview(circleView))`:

   ```
   var circleWidth = CGFloat(200)
   var circleHeight = circleWidth
   // Create a new CircleView
   var circleView = CircleView(frame: CGRectMake(200, 0, circleWidth, circleHeight))
   ```

   It's crashing with:

   ```
   Theard 1 : EXC_BAD_ACCESS (CODE=1,ADDRESS=0X0).
   ```

Comment: Why do you want to add a new view every second? That's going to add up really quick. Perhaps you're trying to move `circleView` to a new location every second instead?

Comment: Also, in the future, if you have two questions, you should really post them separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, yes, you can get the `x`/`y` position of any `UIView` easily; it's also easy to get the coordinates of the center of the screen.

A `UIView`'s position (in the coordinate system of its `superview`) is here:

```
view.frame.origin
```

***Note:** The `origin` is the top-left corner of the `UIView`.*

The center of the screen can be determined like this:

```
let screenBounds = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
let centerOfScreen = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(screenBounds), y: CGRectGetMidY(screenBounds))
```

You probably want the center of the `UIView` you're adding your new view to though, that's pretty much the same, just replace `UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds` with `view.bounds` (where `view` is the `UIView` you're adding your new view to).

Second, you're timer is crashing because you're giving it an invalid `Selector`.  You can't create a `Selector` by passing it a function directly, you need to pass it a `String` containing the name of the function you want it to point to. When you do this:

```
Selector(view.addSubview(circleView))
```

You're actually calling `view.addSubview(circleView)` immediately and passing the value it returns to `Selector`.  Since `addSubview` returns `Void`, you're essentially creating a `Selector` pointing to `nil`, which is invalid. When your `NSTimer` fires, it tries to call that `nil` `Selector` and crashes.

The correct way to do what your code is attempting is to create a new function that adds your `CircleView` and pass the name of that function to `Selector`:

```
func addCircleView() {
    var circleWidth = CGFloat(200)
    var circleHeight = circleWidth
    // Create a new CircleView
    var circleView = CircleView(frame: CGRectMake(200, 0, circleWidth, circleHeight))
    view.addSubview(circleView)
}
```

And then setup your `NSTimer` like so:

```
var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("addCircleView"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

***Note:** You don't actually need to put `Selector` around `"addCircleView"`, Swift will figure out that you need a `Selector` there and convert a string literal to it automatically.*

Comment: omg i wish i could up vote you(no rep) !! :D awesome answer!! i have another question if i may, is it possible to draw the circle in a flow way? like this img for example : http://i.stack.imgur.com/FP4Hu.png (the blue line), i need it to draw it in a certain amount of time, is it exist? *willing to pay/hire you for more question it's so exciting !!

Comment: @roimulia Glad I could help :) Yes, that's possible. You should post a new question with the details though; I couldn't really answer that in comments ;)